# Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

I'm learning C almost one year and it's my first time that I got that warnings.
**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>   
#include <string.h>


 int socket_creation(FILE* fp){
        int s;
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET){
                printf("Error occurred while creating socket: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                fprintf(fp, "Error occurred while creating socket: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        else{
                printf("Socket creation was successful.\n");
                fprintf(fp, "Socket creation was successful.\n");
        }
        return s;
}


void connect_to_server(int s, struct sockaddr_in ClientService, FILE* fp){
        int cResult;
        cResult = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) &ClientService, sizeof(ClientService));
        if (cResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
                printf("connection to the server has been failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                fprintf(fp, "connection to the server has been failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                cResult = closesocket(s);
                if (cResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
                        printf("error occurred while trying to close socket. \n");
                        fprintf(fp, "error occurred while trying to close socket. \n");
                }
                WSACleanup();
        }
        else{
                printf("Connection to serevr has been made successfully. \n");
                fprintf(fp, "Connection to serevr has been made successfully. \n");
        }
}

int send_to_serv(char buffer[], int s){
        int sendto;
        sendto = send(s, buffer, 1024, 0);
        if (sendto == -1)
                printf("\nError: couldn't send the Code.\n", buffer);
        else printf("\nCode: <%s> SENT.\n", buffer);
        return sendto;
}

int recv_from_serv(int s, int* numberLines, FILE *fp){

        int recvfrom;
        char buffer[1024] = "";

        recvfrom = recv(s, buffer, 1024, 0);
        if (recvfrom == -1)
        printf("\nError: couldn't receive Code. !\n");
        else printf("\nRespond: <%s>, RECEIVED. \n", buffer);
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
        fprintf(fp, buffer);

        *numberLines = atoi(buffer + 3);
        return recvfrom;
}

int main() {

        WSADATA info;
        int error, s;
        int sResults, sendError, recvError,convert2;
        char buffer[1024] = "";
        char recvbuf[1024] = "";
        int numberLines, i, temp, convert;
        char converted_num[1024] = "";
        struct sockaddr_in ClientService;
        FILE *fp = fopen("stored_data.txt", "w");
        char* lines_array;
        error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &info);

        if (error != 0){
                printf("WSAstartup failed with error: %d\n", error);
                exit(1);
        }

        for (i=0; i <=numberLines; i++) {
                lines_array[i]=NULL;
        }
        s = socket_creation(fp);

        ClientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
        ClientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("54.209.143.42");
        ClientService.sin_port = htons(6714);

        connect_to_server(s, ClientService, fp);

        strcpy(buffer, "100");
        sendError = send_to_serv(buffer, s);
        recvError = recv_from_serv(s, &numberLines, fp);

        strcpy(buffer, "400");
        sendError = send_to_serv(buffer, s);
        recvError = recv_from_serv(s, &numberLines, fp);
        printf("\nNumber of Lines are: %d\n", numberLines);

        lines_array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*numberLines);
        temp = numberLines;

        for (i = 0; i < temp; i++){
                convert = 5000001 + i;
                _itoa(convert, converted_num, 10);
                sendError = send_to_serv(converted_num, s);
                convert2=atoi(convert);
                convert=convert%10000;
                if(convert2==0) {
                        for(i=0; i<=1024; i++) {
                                buffer[i]=0;
                        }
                        lines_array= (convert);
                        recv_from_serv(s, &numberLines, fp);
                }
                else{
                        for(i=0; i<=1024; i++) {
                                buffer[i]=0;
                        }
                }
        }

        close(fp);
        //system("PkAUSE>nul");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
 }
```

**This is that output that my compiler (MinGW) giving to me:**

> finalproject1.c: In function `main': finalproject1.c:87: warning:
>   assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   finalproject1.c:113: warning: passing arg 1 of`atoi' makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast finalproject1.c:119: warning: assignment
>   makes pointer from integer without a cast finalproject1.c:133:3:
>   warning: no newline at end of file

Please help me I don't know what to do and my guid told me to "Google it" when I asked him to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that triggers the warning is:

```
lines_array[i]=NULL;
```

and this variable is declared like so:

```
char* lines_array;
```

so you're cramming a pointer (the `NULL` macro expands to a pointer-type value on your system) into a single `char`, which won't fit and is a very strange thing to be doing.

Probably you wanted an array of character pointers, i.e.

```
char **lines_array;
```

but then you must of course allocate the array once you know how many lines you're going to be dealing with.

Comment: It's work! but I still getting more warnings :( 

>finalproject1.c: In function `main':
 finalproject1.c:114: warning: passing arg 1 of `atoi' makes pointer from integer
 without a cast
 finalproject1.c:120: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer  without a cast
 finalproject1.c:134:3: warning: no newline at end of file

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i can see you are using an integer **numberLines** as a condition in your for loop without initializing it first:

```
int numberLines;
for (i=0; i <=numberLines; i++) {
            lines_array[i]=NULL;
    }
```

Simply if you want to initialize your array to null you can initialize it as:

```
char* lines_array = null;
```

Try this and let me know if the warnings still exist.